# How to build multiport Ethernet switch?

Tags: ethernet, switching, phy, mac

I have been researching how to build managed/multiport Ethernet switch. There are things that I do not understand and would like to know more.

1. Some Ethernet switches have built in MACs and if I use one of these, do I have to use an Ethernet controller or are MACs inside enough for switching? or are MACs and Ethernet controllers unrelated?
2. Some Ethernet switches have internal PHYs but not for all the ports. Do ports that do not have internal PHYs need external PHY connection?
3. What components do I need in general to build Ethernet switch?

Comment: Have you opened up a commercial ethernet switch to see how it’s done? Basically you start with an ethernet switch chip. One port is normally used for the microprocessor so it can talk via ethernet. Some switch chips have a mac for this, some have a RMII or similar interface to a MAC. The setup of the switch is usually done via SPI. The micro normally will be running linux, so you’ll  need a dram, serial flash and suitable microprocessor along with the requisite power supplies and ethernet magjacks.

Comment: @Kartman thanks a lot for the comment. I will consider your list of components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a "block diagram" level, every port needs a connector, a transformer (or "magnetics"), a PHY and a MAC. They can be inside or outside the switch, but you need them. The magnetics will not be inside the switch because they are too big, but sometimes they will be inside the connector.

The actual switch part connects to all of the MACs.

And you need some kind of CPU to be in charge of the whole system. Probably an ARM-based microcontroller, in this day and age. To make a managed switch, you do want your CPU to run a web server so the administrator can set the configuration of the switch, so it has to be fast enough to handle that. There are switch chips which will just start switching as soon as they receive power, and don't have any configuration, but since you're making a managed switch and not an unmanaged switch, you won't be using one of those.

You might have port designed to connect the actual switch part to the CPU. Because this connection is all on the same circuit board, it's not always necessary to have all the parts for a "proper" connection - you can take shortcuts. For example, a proper PHY is probably not necessary.

Some microcontrollers have a built-in MAC, that connects to an external PHY. For convenience, some switch chips have *two* built-in PHYs that connect to each other. So when you connect this to your microcontroller, it makes a chain of CPU---MAC---PHY---PHY---MAC---switch and works like normal without needing an extra PHY chip. This is not universal - it depends on the particular chip you use. Of course, the PHY---PHY is not just two normal PHYs but probably uses some shortcuts.

Other times, the switch might have a built-in MAC, and you can connect it to a CPU which is designed to connect to a separate MAC. (I think this is rare)

You would use this special port to send and receive packets on your CPU, so that your web server (and any other features like SNMP) are connected to the computers that people plug into the switch. If you don't have a special port for this, you'll have to use one of the normal ports.

The switch might also have a different type of control port such as SPI or I2C, which the CPU would use to tell the switch about the VLANs the system administrator has configured. Sometimes, there's no separate control port and you control the switch by sending special Ethernet packets to the special CPU Ethernet port. Sometimes, you can send and receive packets through the control port and you don't need a CPU Ethernet port. All depends on the design of the chip you use.